# база данных не подключается при установкве joomla

Tags: joomla, база-данных

помигите подключить базу данных при установке joomla на nic.ru, база данных есть но joomla не может подключится к этой базе данных, что мне делать
создал 2 базы данных, в phpmyadmin они есть но почему то показано что они не подключены к пользователю
Подскажите как ещё можно войти в phpMyAdmin через адресную строку, а то у меня через хост какая-та фигня выходит

Comment: боюсь прослыть кэпом, но ты не пробовал их подключить через панель хостера?

Comment: тогда писать в сапорт хостера, это уже их проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пиши суппорт. Это реальная проблема. phpMyAdmin не обманывает, он показывает то что есть на  самом деле

Answer (score 0):

в панели хостера показано что они подключены, а в phpMyAdmin указано что у пользователя базы данных нет, при этом создать ещё одного пользователя я не могу, так как тарифом это не предусмотренно

Comment: Вы когда жали кнопку "ответить", понимали значение этого слова? А сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

Это откуда же должны расти руки, чтобы такая ситуация произошла...
[Решение](http://hosting.nic.ru/support/shift_bd_mysql.shtml)